# Invalid Cipher Text Exception while decrypting AES key using RSA

Tags: c#, encryption, cryptography, aes, rsa

I'm working on encrypt/decrypt request/response on both angular 6 and .net core api side. I'm encrypting data in angular using AES and encrypting AES key using RSA public key and sending it to .net core api. I have created action filter to decrypt the request, and to decrypt the request first I have to decrypt the AES key using RSA private key but it is giving me an error while decrypting AES key using RSA private key:

> - ex  {Org.BouncyCastle.Crypto.InvalidCipherTextException: block incorrect
>     at Org.BouncyCastle.Crypto.Encodings.Pkcs1Encoding.DecodeBlock(Byte[] input, Int32 inOff, Int32 inLen)
>     at Phyzii.Core.Api.Security.RSA.Decrypt(String cipherText)}  System.Exception {Org.BouncyCastle.Crypto.InvalidCipherTextException}

**Here is my RSA encryption code at angular side:**

```
import JSEncrypt from 'jsencrypt';
encryptObj = new JSEncrypt();
transitionIn(data: any) {
    this.aesSecretKey=this.makeUniqueKey(10);
    console.log(this.aesSecretKey);
    this.data.DATAOBJ = this.aesEncrypt(this.aesSecretKey, data);
    this.encryptObj.setPublicKey(this.publicKeyClient);
    this.data.KEY = this.encryptObj.encrypt(this.aesSecretKey);
    return this.data;
}
```

**Here is my RSA decryption code at C# side:**

```
private static AsymmetricCipherKeyPair ReadPemFile(string flag)
{
    string filePath = flag == "PUBLIC" ? "D:/Crypto/private_key.pem" : "D:/Crypto/private_key_server.pem";
    AsymmetricCipherKeyPair keys;
    using (var reader = File.OpenText(filePath))// file containing RSA PKCS1 private key
        keys = (AsymmetricCipherKeyPair)new PemReader(reader).ReadObject();
    AsymmetricKeyParameter private_key = keys.Private;
    AsymmetricKeyParameter public_key = keys.Public;
    return keys;
}


//cipherText = "gOItOryuGy0UXHfoNqo0omcXLIOS6dhLJas5zeDNA7MfvsHYwP4ccSWU9JwTrIRiYUq/NB9oRn62ZQ5ynDnsGXUmHfVT4oPxtQZE1fXTTMN5ycfgthegesmXoZMMcWxA/wnwjLAgE17MNaunKY307W+nyc3jEMT1QsWUoOBESo0="
public static string Decrypt(string cipherText) 
{
    try
    {
        byte[] cipherTextBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(cipherText);
        AsymmetricCipherKeyPair keys = ReadPemFile("PRIVATE");
        AsymmetricKeyParameter private_key = keys.Private;

        // Pure mathematical RSA implementation
        // RsaEngine eng = new RsaEngine();

        // PKCS1 v1.5 paddings
        // Pkcs1Encoding eng = new Pkcs1Encoding(new RsaEngine());

        // PKCS1 OAEP paddings
        Pkcs1Encoding eng = new Pkcs1Encoding(new RsaEngine());
        eng.Init(false, private_key);

        int length = cipherTextBytes.Length;
        int blockSize = eng.GetInputBlockSize();
        List<byte> plainTextBytes = new List<byte>();
        for (int chunkPosition = 0; chunkPosition < length; chunkPosition += blockSize)
        {
            int chunkSize = Math.Min(blockSize, length - chunkPosition);
            plainTextBytes.AddRange(eng.ProcessBlock(cipherTextBytes, chunkPosition, chunkSize));
        }
        return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(plainTextBytes.ToArray());
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw ex;
    }
}
```

and If i set `true` in Pkcs1Encoding Init

```
Pkcs1Encoding eng = new Pkcs1Encoding(new RsaEngine());
eng.Init(true, private_key);
```

Then it is decrypting data in this format `�����Ŧ���%�Rc��\u000e�\b\u0004����I�]&P~�+�뛡�^s�V�ʗ' \b��?Jv�F�ge\u001b�S���^�\u0002��v/|�vh�}�z�[A�}��\u0002u\\�Pp����\u0011k9\u001e\n�E\b�\u0003��\u001a#��}��y��\u000eTG�U\a�A_KV�\u007fs����?3���*/*\n\n~�w�Q��'��\a:���q��BH\u0004R�#c��'d�\u001f���\0 5\u007f���fs�<���\u0012\t����|�[\u0015\b+��8\u0003`�[�v����Ǹ��8ځ\u001cԞv�{=���@-o\u0004�I\u0014J�\0#4`

which is incorrect,
what can be the issue?

Comment: One also need to see the encryption, too. Also, did you convert the ciphertext to base64 before transmit?

Comment: I'd usually recommend that if you're trying to encrypt with one tech stack and decrypt with another you first build the full round-trip in both stacks, and break it down as much as possible so that you can compare the outputs of both at as many stages as possible. Once you have the round trip in both stacks and they're in full agreement on the journey the data takes, it's far easier to swap one for the other at the midway point.

Comment: I'm using JSEncrypt in angular to encrypt data using RSA. & I'm converting it to base64 at c# side, you can check it in my code @kelalaka

Comment: @kelalaka See, now I've updated the answer with RSA encryption at angular side

Comment: I can't reproduce the issue. Encryption with JSEncrypt (3.0.0-rc.1, without Angular) and decryption with C# (.NET Core 2.2, your code) work. Are you sure that your public and private key are compatible, i.e. does decryption work on the angular side? Which JSEncrypt-version do you use? My suggestion: Create a **test** RSA key pair and post the private and public key as PEM, and also a **test** AES key to encrypt (raw or encoded the way you use it), and (one of) the ciphertexts generated with JSEncrypt.

Comment: There was an issue in my private key and public key, It worked after changing the keys